# Forever not creating log files even though log options are specified

Tags: node.js, forever

I am executing following command including options to create log files but for some reason its not creating log files:

```
forever start bin/www -e logs/error.log -l logs/logs.log
```

this does not seem to work. Any ideas fellows?

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. I got working by specifying `sourceDir` option in forever config json file.

Specifying absolute path is necessary. Also specifying `sourceDir` options is necessary too.

```
{
    "uid": "app",
    "append": true,
    "watch": true,
    "script": "bin/www",
    "sourceDir": "/messaging/",
    "logFile": "/messaging/logs/log.log",      
    "errFile": "/messaging/logs/err.log"
}
```

Then started forever using forever start `forever_config.json` and it worked.